# How get number of rows result a query in SQL (C ANSI)?

Tags: c, select, sqlite, count, mysql-num-rows

I need get the number of row result a query in SQLite in C
Example:

```
SELECT name, age FROM test WHERE age > 18
```

How i can get the number of rows this query in SQLite C.

I see the command sqlite3_total_changes() to affected row (When use INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE),
sqlite3_column_count() to get the number of column, but i need the number of rows, sqlite3_column_bytes().

I need a function equal mysql_num_rows from PHP.

case the example return 3 lines, how i can get 3 lines SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
SELECT Count(name) FROM test WHERE age > 18
```

This will count all rows in test where age > 18 and name is not null.  If you want to count the ones with null name then use

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM test WHERE age > 18
```

Here is some documentation:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Comment: do not can count the statment or buffer and div by return  of sqlite3_column_bytes() ? is really necessary execute two sql?

Comment: Yes it is necessary -- or you can cache the results as a table and do a count on that.  In most cases this will perform worse.

Comment: SQLite calculates the currently returned rows on the fly while you're stepping through them; the total number is never known.